Xamarin - Manifest merger issue
I am newbie to Xamarin application
Below is the details of packages included
<ItemGroup>
 
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="5.0.0.2662" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Maps" Version="5.0.0.2515" />
    <PackageReference Include="Prism.Unity.Forms" Version="7.2.0.1422" />
    <PackageReference Include="Acr.UserDialogs" Version="7.1.0.514" />
    <PackageReference Include="Com.Airbnb.Xamarin.Forms.Lottie" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Plugin.Permissions" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Prism.Plugin.Popups" Version="7.2.0.1046" />
    <PackageReference Include="Scandit.BarcodePicker.Unified" Version="5.16.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="SlideOverKit" Version="2.1.6.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.7.335" />
    <PackageReference Include="SQLiteNetExtensions" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.core" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugin.Connectivity" Version="3.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugin.DeviceInfo" Version="4.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Forms" Version="2.4.11.982" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms" Version="2.4.11.982" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="10.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="ZXing.Net.Mobile" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms" Version="2.4.1" />

   
    <PackageReference Include="LinkOS_Xamarin_SDK" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Mono.Data.Sqlite.Portable" Version="1.0.3.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="PCLCrypto" Version="2.0.147" />
    <PackageReference Include="SegmentedControl.FormsPlugin" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugin.Geolocator" Version="4.5.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugins.Settings" Version="4.0.0.10-beta" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Controls.SignaturePad.Forms" Version="3.0.0" />

    
    <PackageReference Include="DynamicStackLayout" Version="2017.12.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Xamarin.Pdf" Version="16.2.0.50" />
    <PackageReference Include="LiveXAML" Version="2.1.72" />
    <PackageReference Include="Forms9Patch" Version="1.6.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp.Svg" Version="1.59.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp.Views.Forms" Version="1.59.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Google.Android.Material" Version="1.4.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat" Version="1.6.1.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.V4" Version="1.0.0.20" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.CardView" Version="1.0.0.20" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.MediaRouter" Version="1.3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.AppCompatResources">
      <Version>1.6.1.7</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration" Version="1.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Honeywell.BarcodeReader">
      <Version>1.32.7.10</Version>
    </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>

Error while building:
/Users/myname/Documents/myname/MyApp/My.App.Mobile/My.App.Mobile.Android/obj/Release/AndroidManifest.xml(16,16): Error AMM0000: /Users/myname/Documents/myname/MyApp/My.App.Mobile/My.App.Mobile.Android/obj/Release/lp/111/jl/AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
    Namespace 'com.google.android.gms.base' used in: AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
/Users/myname/Documents/myname/MyApp/My.App.Mobile/My.App.Mobile.Android/obj/Release/lp/180/jl/AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
    Namespace 'com.google.android.gms.common' used in: AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
/Users/myname/Documents/myname/MyApp/My.App.Mobile/My.App.Mobile.Android/obj/Release/lp/181/jl/AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
    Namespace 'com.google.android.gms.tasks' used in: AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.
/Users/myname/Documents/myname/MyApp/My.App.Mobile/My.App.Mobile.Android/obj/Release/lp/183/jl/AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
    Namespace 'com.google.android.gms.maps' used in: AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml.

    Attribute application@label value=(My.App.Mobile.Android) from AndroidManifest.xml:26:16-58
    is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:16:9-41 value=(@string/app_name).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:3-49:17 to override.
Directory 'obj/Release/lp/111' is from 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base.dll'.
Directory 'obj/Release/lp/180' is from 'playservicesbasement-17.1.0.aar'.
Directory 'obj/Release/lp/181' is from 'playservicestasks-17.0.0.aar'.
Directory 'obj/Release/lp/183' is from 'playservicesmaps-17.0.0.aar'. (AMM0000) (My.App.Mobile.Android) java

What I have tried
In AndroidManifest.xml, inside <application> tag, I tried adding tools:replace="android:label" but after rebuilding, it is removed automatically and it shows the same error.
